# Reference hidden field generated from jQuery from C# with ASP.NET

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, hidden-field

I am using Drew Wilson's AutoSuggest jQuery plugin http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/autosuggest-jquery-plugin with ASP.NET. I'd like to be able to reference the hidden field generated by the plugin where the selected items are stored in my C# code behind, but I don't know how to reference a hidden field without a runat="server" attribute. Currently, I have the value of the plugin's hidden field being copied into another hidden field that I can access with server side code, but it's not the best method for what I'm trying to achieve. Issues arise when I submit my form and I've deleted an item from my selections, but it still submits the deleted item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Request["hiddenInputName"]` to get it's value.

Answer (score 2):

Any form fields posted to the server, whether or not they were originally part of your server-side prepared form, are accessible in `Request.Form`, for instance using `Request.Form["postedFieldName"]`.